# VueJS: Como leio um atributo src que já está dentro de uma diretiva v-html?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

O conteúdo contido na string `videosOnScreen` é transformado em HTML pela diretiva `v-html`, mas não consegue encontrar o caminho do atributo `src`.

Existe alguma forma em que este atributo possa ser lido?

```
<template>
    <div class="media" v-html="videoPlaying"></div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            videoPlaying: "",
        };
    },
    async mounted() {
        console.log(await this.getPlayersInfo());        
    },
    methods: {    
        async getPlayersInfo() {
            videoWidth = 500
            videoHeight = 300

            videosOnScreen = '<video muted width="' + videoWidth + '" height="' + videoHeight + '" autoplay src="../../assets/video/first-video.mp4"></video>'
            this.videoPlaying = videosOnScreen
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ele não carrega o video ou não renderiza o componente? OBS: voce deveria declarar as variáveis usando `const`

Comment: Elas estão declaradas, acabei não colocando essa parte do código. Ele renderiza o video, consigo ver a tela preta de vídeo numa posição, mas o vídeo não inicia, a tela só fica preta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No caso acima, não se deve informar o `src` dessa forma `"../../assets/video/first-video.mp4"`, porque no final, não é este caminho que o VueJS usa para servir os arquivos estáticos.

Por exemplo, em um projeto meu, eu tenho um arquivo `.png` dentro de `assets`, mas se eu inspecionar o HTML da página, a imagem está sendo servida de outro diretório, no meu caso, o `src` dela é `/img/gmblogoatual.4caa3f41.png`. Veja que começa por `/img` e não `/assets` ou `../../assets`, enfim.

Como você quer gerar um elemento HTML através de uma string, primeiro temos que importar o arquivo que será referenciado no `src`.

Como fazemos isso?

Usando o `require('...')` para importar o arquivo dentro de `assets`.

No seu código, faremos o seguinte:

1. Após `videoPlaying`, vamos declarar uma variável chamada `videoUrl` que vai fazer o *import* do arquivo de vídeo e receber o link (path ou caminho) relativo ao arquivo de vídeo. Na função `data`:

```js
return {
        videoPlaying: "",       // ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ aquele seu caminho fica no "require"
        videoUrl: require("../../assets/video/first-video.mp4"),
};
```

2. Vamos trabalhar com a função `getPlayersInfo`. Vou usar *template string* para facilitar a leitura. Onde você usava `src="../../assets/video/first-video.mp4"`, vamos fazer dessa forma:

```js
async getPlayersInfo() {
  const videoWidth = 500;
  const videoHeight = 300;

  this.videoPlaying =
    `<video width="${videoWidth}" controls height="${videoHeight}" autoplay src="${this.videoUrl}"></video>`;
},
```

Veja que agora em `src` eu passei o valor do `this.videoUrl`. Esta variável é que vai ser responsável por resolver (graças ao VueJS) o caminho que deve ser usado para servir o arquivo de vídeo.

Creio que não precise mudar mais nada no seu código. Veja como ficaria:

```
<template>
  <div class="media" v-html="videoPlaying"></div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        videoPlaying: '', // ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ aquele seu caminho fica no "require"
        videoUrl: require('../../assets/video/first-video.mp4')
      };
    },
    async mounted() {
      await this.getPlayersInfo(); // retirei o console.log
    },
    methods: {
      async getPlayersInfo() {
        const videoWidth = 500;
        const videoHeight = 300;

        this.videoPlaying = `<video width="${videoWidth}" controls height="${videoHeight}" autoplay src="${this.videoUrl}"></video>`;
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Após os testes arqui, recriando as condições do seu código, esse foi o meu resultado ao inspecionar o HTML final da página:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare que mesmo importanto de `assets`, o caminho final foi para `src="/media/first-video.9684e373.mp4"`, pois o VueJS gera outras pastas e salva os arquivos nelas para servir na build final.

Repare também que ele gerou um `id` único para o arquivo estático servido (`first-video.9684e373.mp4`).

---

## Atenção

Use a diretiva `v-html` com cautela. Use-a apenas com conteúdos controlados e gerenciados por você, pois se for depender de um conteúdo desconhecido, pode gerar sérios problemas e brechas para ataques [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), como descrito e [alertado pela própria documentação](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-text):

> Dynamically rendering arbitrary HTML on your website can be very dangerous because it can easily lead to XSS attacks (opens new window). Only use v-html on trusted content and never on user-provided content.

Comment: Muito obrigado, cara. Eu já tinha tentando usar o require, mas por ter colocado direto no src de dentro da string de vídeo, acabou não funcionando. Meu único problema no momento é que os videos (estou usando a string dentro de uma estrutura de repetição agora) aparecem na tela antes de serem carregados, então um acaba aparecendo antes do outro. Você conhece alguma função ou tem alguem sugestão que eu possa usar pro template só renderizar os vídeos após serem carregados? De qualquer modo, obrigadão.

Comment: Posso ter uma ideia de como fazer, mas como se trata de um outro problema, voce teria que criar um nova pergunta, postar o código relevante, imagens de como aparece, etc....

Comment: Acabei de publicar a minha dúvida, caso possa dar uma ajuda